# Combining two SQL queries to get all from one table with where clause and only count of occurrences from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a PHP script which runs 2 queries. The first query is

```
"SELECT PID , EXPERIENCE , LASTLOGIN , WON , LOST , TIED , PRODUCT1_COUNT , PRODUCT2_COUNT , PRODUCT3_COUNT , AD_FREE , CODENAME , FB_UID , WSBALANCE , BEST_GAME_SCORE , BEST_WORD_SCORE , BEST_MOVE_SCORE , MW_PLAYED 
 FROM user 
 WHERE (PID > 9 AND (('. $serverTime .'- LASTLOGIN < 1209600) OR (AD_FREE + PRODUCT1_COUNT + PRODUCT2_COUNT + PRODUCT3_COUNT + PRODUCT4_COUNT ) > 0 ))"
```

Then the next step in the script is to iterate through each row of this query to build an html table. In the course of that I am querying a second table (games1) to get a count of the number of active games the first query returns.

```
$id = $row['PID'];

$pSQL = "SELECT COUNT(SID) AS c 
         FROM games1 
         WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND (P1_UID = $id OR P2_UID = $id OR P3_UID = $id OR P4_UID = $id)";
```

I've been trying to wrap my brain around how to use join to combine these two queries, but I'm just not getting it. I'd greatly appreciate the help as this combination will save our script a bit of time.

Comment: Format your query and remove the incorrect tags.`SELECT blah blah blah FROM(select 1 JOIN select 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join,below query will give the data from user table and the count from game table per user

```
SELECT 
  u.PID,
  u.EXPERIENCE,
  u.LASTLOGIN,
  u.WON,
  u.LOST,
  u.TIED,
  u.PRODUCT1_COUNT,
  u.PRODUCT2_COUNT,
  u.PRODUCT3_COUNT,
  u.AD_FREE,
  u.CODENAME,
  u.FB_UID,
  u.WSBALANCE,
  u.BEST_GAME_SCORE,
  u.BEST_WORD_SCORE,
  u.BEST_MOVE_SCORE,
  u.MW_PLAYED ,
  COUNT(g.SID) AS c  
FROM
  `user` u
  LEFT JOIN games1 g
  ON (
    (g.P1_UID = u.PID
    OR g.P2_UID = u.PID
    OR g.P3_UID = u.PID
    OR g.P4_UID = u.PID) AND  g.ACTIVE = 1 
  ) 
WHERE (PID > 9 
    AND (( '. $serverTime .' - u.LASTLOGIN < 1209600) 
      OR (u.AD_FREE + u.PRODUCT1_COUNT + u.PRODUCT2_COUNT + u.PRODUCT3_COUNT + u.PRODUCT4_COUNT) > 0)
  ) 
  GROUP BY u.PID
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. Unfortunately, the time required for this SQL statement is around 6 seconds and when I had them separated it was around 6 seconds too...The games1 table is only 2,000 records and the user table is only 800 records. Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: @user2388129 make sure you do have index for your columns from games1 table *P1_UID,P2_UID,P3_UID,P4_UID* if they are not indexed then add a composite index i.e *ALTER TABLE `games1 ` ADD INDEX `test_index` (`P1_UID`, `P2_UID`,`P3_UID`,`P4_UID`,`ACTIVE`);* it will help you

Comment: thank you I will try that out. I believe I was confused between indexes on columns and primary keys... I think I've got it now. But now I have to figure out what to index in my tables. More reading! Yay!